# Query rewrite and Tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, query-tuning

I have the below query that is the cause of performance degradation, can someone help to rewrite this query so that it could perform better.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT ITEMDETAIL0_.depid AS COL_0_0_ 
        FROM   xxxxxxxxxx.rptdepitemdetails ITEMDETAIL0_ 
               cross join xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxorg ORGANIZATI1_ 
        WHERE  ITEMDETAIL0_.bankname =? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.customerid = ORGANIZATI1_.id 
               AND ORGANIZATI1_.uniquename =? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createuser =? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate >=? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate <=? 
               AND ( ITEMDETAIL0_.captureworktype IN ( ? ) ) 
               AND ( ITEMDETAIL0_.depstatus IN ( ?, ? ) ) 
        GROUP  BY ITEMDETAIL0_.depid, 
                  ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate 
        ORDER  BY ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate ASC) 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= ?
```

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Why are you expressing a `JOIN` as a `CROSS JOIN`?  Use the `ON` clause!

Comment: You need to tell what you want to achieve. Looking at your query i can say making `CROSS` join is anyways going to take time

Comment: Many times query tunning relies not upon rewriting the query but in normalizing your data correctly and the smart use of indexes.

Comment: Could you add the explain plan of your query? It will be much easier to diagnose your problem correctly.

Comment: @Jaisus  - added the explain plan

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - can you plz help me as suggested to use ON instead of Cross Join

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: What is `depid`? Is it unique in the item details table?

Answer (score 0):

You can write query as follow to avoid cross join and using ON.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT ITEMDETAIL0_.depid AS COL_0_0_ 
        FROM   xxxxxxxxxx.rptdepitemdetails ITEMDETAIL0_ 
               join xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxorg ORGANIZATI1_  on ITEMDETAIL0_.customerid = ORGANIZATI1_.id 
        WHERE  ITEMDETAIL0_.bankname =? 
               AND ORGANIZATI1_.uniquename =? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createuser =? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate >=? 
               AND ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate <=? 
               AND ( ITEMDETAIL0_.captureworktype IN ( ? ) ) 
               AND ( ITEMDETAIL0_.depstatus IN ( ?, ? ) ) 
        GROUP  BY ITEMDETAIL0_.depid, 
                  ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate 
        ORDER  BY ITEMDETAIL0_.createdate ASC) 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= ?
```

Also, creating indexes on id column of xxxxxxxxxxorg and customerid and depid of rptdepitemdetails tables would help.

Comment: I've formatted your SQL code for you. That's very easy to do by the way: just highlight your query and press the `{}` button.